Cygwin: man column contains unexpected characters instead of - (minus sign, hyphen), is it expected?
Cygwin: man column contains unexpected characters instead of - (minus sign, hyphen):
# cygwin
$ man column | grep -P 'table.*truncate' | od -c
0000000                               -   T   ,       -   -   t   a   b
0000020   l   e 342 200 220   t   r   u   n   c   a   t   e       c   o
0000040   l   u   m   n   s  \n
0000046

# linux
$ man column | grep -P 'table.*truncate' | od -c
0000000                               -   T   ,       -   -   t   a   b
0000020   l   e   -   t   r   u   n   c   a   t   e       c   o   l   u
0000040   m   n   s  \n
0000044

Here we see that on Cygwin man column contains unexpected characters instead of - (minus sign, hyphen). Is it expected?

UPD. I've updated Cygwin and the issue is fixed:
$ man column | grep -P 'table.*truncate' | od -c
0000000                                                               T
0000020   h   e       c   o   l   u   m   n       t   e   x   t       c
0000040   a   n       b   e       t   r   u   n   c   a   t   e   d
0000060   w   h   e   n       n   e   c   e   s   s   a   r   y   .
0000100   T   h   e       s   a   m   e       a   s       -   -   t   a
0000120   b   l   e   -   t   r   u   n   c   a   t   e   .  \n
0000140                       -   T   ,       -   -   t   a   b   l   e
0000160   -   t   r   u   n   c   a   t   e       c   o   l   u   m   n
0000200   s  \n
0000202


This might be caused by your $LANG (or $LC_ALL / $LC_CTYPE) being set to 'something.UTF-8'.
Does the problem go away if you run man like this?
LC_ALL=C man column

(LC_ALL overrides pretty much everything, so it shouldn't matter what the other environment variables are set to)
EDIT:
Minus signs (and apostrophes) should be backslash-escaped in manpages. No one actually escapes them though, which is why, on *BSD and certain Linux systems, groff is specifically instructed not to mess with those unescaped dashes.
On Cygwin, however, as soon as groff sees that your locale is set to UTF-8, it happily starts converting dashes to hyphens (U+2010) and apostrophes to single quotes (U+2019), which makes certain manpages, ehm, "unsearchable" and "uncopypasteable" (one particularly notorious example being man tmux).

I've updated Cygwin and the issue is fixed (see UPD). Hence, I cannot reproduce the issue (and test with LC_ALL=C man column) any longer. I've tried (after the updating) different LC_ALL and couldn't reproduce the issue. For example, diff <(man column | grep -P 'table.*truncate' | od -c) <(LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 man column | grep -P 'table.*truncate' | od -c) produces nothing (expected).

@pmor The update must have fixed it. I do have this problem on my Cygwin system(s), but not with that particular manpage. I've updated my answer with a brief explanation of why this happens.

Thanks. Re: "makes certain manpages, ehm, "unsearchable" and "uncopypasteable": exactly. I've stumbled the issue while grepping the output of man column.

@pmor It turns out that the manpage in question underwent a major revamp somewhere around util-linux-2.39. Everything is properly escaped now, whereas in util-linux-2.33.1-3, most of the options looked like this: \-\-table-truncate. I still sort of wish I could make groff behave the way it does on *BSD, instead of having to alias man to LC_ALL=C man

Using this bit of python reveals that those 3 octets displayed in octal are the UTF-8 representation of a Unicode hyphen, which is different from the ASCII minus sign.
$ python
>>> b = b"\342\200\220"
>>> c = b.decode('utf8')
>>> c
'‐'
>>> hex(ord(c))
'0x2010'
>>> ^d
$

